# Generate Recursion Tree of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: plotting, recursion

I'm using this example to study Mathematics.[Example Demo](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IterationVersusRecursionInTheFibonacciSequence/). In this example, before generating recursion tree, she flats the function. But I have a difficultly to understand how flatten works, especially **the 3rd line** of the code below. Could someone teach me? Thank you very much.

```
f[___, 0] := {};
f[___, 1] := {};
f[m___, p_] := {{m, p} -> {m, p, p - 1}, {m, p} -> {m, p, p - 2}, //How to understand this line?
f[m, p, p - 1], f[m, p, p - 2]}
j[n_] := f[n] // Flatten
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand `j[n__]:= f[n] //Flatten` we need to understand `f[n]`. As an example, take `f[3]`.

MMA applies more specific definitions first. In this case this will be `f[m___, p_]`, where m is empty. Therefore, we replace `f[3]` by

```
{{3} -> {3, 2}, {3} -> {3, 1}, f[3,2],f[3,1]}.
```

`f[3, 1]` is, by definition, an empty list.

`f[3, 2]` is, by the pattern: `f[m___, p_]`,

```
{{3, 2} -> {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2} -> {3, 2, 0}, f[3, 2, 1], f3, 2, 0]}.
```

`f[3, 2, 1]` and `f3, 2, 0]` are by definition empty lists, so this is:

```
{{3, 2} -> {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2} -> {3, 2, 0}, {}, {}}
```

Inserting `f[3, 2]` and `f[3, 1]` in the list above:

```
{{3} -> {3, 2}, {3} -> {3, 1}, {{3, 2} -> {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2} -> {3, 2, 0}, {}, {}}, {}}
```

`Flatten` will take away the empty lists. So we finally get:

```
{{3} -> {3, 2}, {3} -> {3, 1}, {3, 2} -> {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2} -> {3, 2, 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I don't understand f[m___, p_] := {{m, p} -> {m, p, p - 1}, {m, p} -> {m, p, p - 2}. What does this step {{m, p} -> {m, p, p - 1} mean? Sorry I'm new to use Mathematic so it's must be very naive question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: MMA works not like other languages, it is a replacement system That means, you define patters and replacements. If MMA finds a pattern it replaces it with the replacement and keeps on doing this until nothing changes anymore. ` f[m___, p_] := {{m, p} -> {m, p, p - 1}, {m, p}` defines a pattern ` f[m___, p_] ` and a replacement: `{{m, p} -> {m, p, p - 1}, {m, p} -> {m, p, p - 2}`. If MMA find a part that matches the pattern, it replaces it by the replacement. Look  pattern matching up in the help. E.g. `_` means "anything". You may name this, e.g. `p_`. `__`means one or more "anythings"  e.t.c

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much.